# ValueError with condition statement on csv file - I/O operation on closed file

Tags: csv, import, opencsv

```
import csv
with open ('albumlist.csv','r') as newalbumlist1:
    reader = csv.DictReader(newalbumlist1)


funkalbums = [row for row in newalbumlist1 if(row['Genre'] == 'Funk' and
                ('Pop Rock' in row['Subgenre'] or 'Disco' in row['Subgenre'])
                                           )
            ]  
print(len(funkalbums))
```

I have an error running this piece of code. can someone help?
........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 6
      2 with open ('albumlist.csv','r') as newalbumlist1:
      3     reader = csv.DictReader(newalbumlist1)
----> 6 funkalbums = [row for row in newalbumlist1 if(row['Genre'] == 'Funk' and
      7                 ('Pop Rock' in row['Subgenre'] or 'Disco' in row['Subgenre'])
      8                                            )
      9             ]
     10 print(len(funkalbums))